# Why does retry not working in my Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins v2.263.3

I have the following code that just aims to upload a zip file to our private Nexus repo. I want it to try 3 times. Note all the variables used are defined somewhere else in the script, and are all valid.

```groovy
    withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',
                      credentialsId:'nexus-user',
                      usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USR',
                      passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PW']]) {
      final Integer maxTries = 3
      Integer numTries = 1
      retry(maxTries) {
        timeout(time: 5) { // Timeout in minutes
          println "Trying $numTries/$maxTries upload to file server."
          numTries++
          sh """
            curl -v -u $NEXUS_USR:$NEXUS_PW --upload-file $artifact $remoteUrl/$remoteDir/$artifact
          """
        }
      }
    }
```

However, when the pipeline just quits if it fails after the first try, that is, it just ignores the `retry{}` block. What am I missing?

Comment: Does the failure of your `sh` step method throw an exception, or does it just return an exit code > 1?

Comment: It just returns a non-zero error code.

Comment: There was an issue ([JENKINS-51454](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-51454)) with the [Pipeline: Basic Steps Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/) in which the plugin did not retry for any `FlowInterruptedException` that was raised from the code execution.
The issue was recently fixed so updating this plugin should solve your problem.